# Loading fontspec makes Greek maths styles vanish

Tags: math-mode, xetex, luatex, fontspec

If I load `fontspec`, without `unicode-math` or `mathspec`, in LuaLaTex or XeLaTeX, I can no longer use `\mathsf{\Phi}`, `\mathbf{\Phi}`, and maybe other variants.

Demo:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\[ \Phi\mathbf{\Phi}\mathsf{\Phi} \qquad A\mathbf{A}\mathsf{A} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: example 1]

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\[ \Phi\mathbf{\Phi}\mathsf{\Phi} \qquad A\mathbf{A}\mathsf{A} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: example 2]

Why is this? What happened to them? I hadn't realized that just loading `fontspec` would have any effect on math mode...

Is there any way to get the styles back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the `no-math` option:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\[
\Phi\mathbf{\Phi}\mathsf{\Phi} \qquad A\mathbf{A}\mathsf{A}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]